# Casting uint16_t to unsigned int

Tags: c, casting, buffer-overflow, integer-overflow

We have casted 2d array:

```
struct pixel(*image_data)[width] = (struct pixel(*)[width])img->px;
```

1. I didn't get how it casts and allocate memory?

where width:

```
  unsigned width = img->size_x;
```

and struct image:

```
struct image {
   uint16_t size_x;
   uint16_t size_y;
   struct pixel *px;
};
```

2nd question:

What is maximum value that width can hold?

3rd:

If we iterate image_data[x][y] where x and y are long then there is buffer overflow?

Comment: This is defect C code. `struct pixel *` isn't compatible with `struct pixel(*)[width]`. This code may or may not work. You could have undefined behavior all over.

Comment: There is no cast "uint16_t to unsigned int" as suggest by the title in `unsigned width = img->size_x;`

Answer (score 4):

1. The cast doesn't allocate memory. The type of the `image_data` variable is "pointer to array of length `width` of `struct pixel`" (using the value of `width` at the point of declaration of `image_data`), so `image_data + i` is a pointer to the `i`th row (counting from 0) of `struct pixel`.
2. In theory, `width` could be any value up to `SIZE_MAX / sizeof (struct pixel)` but may be limited by other constraints. Also `size_x` and `size_y` in `struct image` are limited by their type `uint16_t` to a maximum value of 65535.
3. If `x >= 0` and `y >= 0` and `y < width` (where `width` still has the value `sizeof (*image_data) / sizeof ((*image_data)[0])`) and the buffer pointed to by `img->px` is at least `sizeof (struct pixel) * (x + 1) * width` bytes long (and correctly aligned for `struct pixel`) then there will be no buffer overrun.

Regarding the definition of the `width` variable:

```
unsigned width = img->size_x;
```

`img->size_x` has type `uint16_t` and the maximum value of `uint16_t` is *exactly* 65535. `width` has type `unsigned int` and the maximum value of `unsigned int` is *at least* 65535, so `width` will be initialized to the value of `img->size_x` without truncation.

In the comments to the question, Lundin mentions that `struct Pixel *` is not compatible with `struct pixel(*)[width]`. That is true, but C allows conversion from one pointer type to another. The behavior is undefined if the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type (the referenced type is `struct pixel [width]` here). It would be highly unusual for an array type to have stricter alignment requirements than the corresponding element type, so that is probably OK. Even if the array type has a stricter alignment requirement than the element type, it is OK as long as the pointer is in fact correctly aligned. If `img->px` points to a block allocated by `malloc`, `calloc` or similar, then it is correctly aligned for any object type that has a "fundamental" alignment, so that is OK. The main problem is that if the pixel data is accessed via both `img->px` and `image_data` then that would violate the *strict aliasing rule* because the pointers have incompatible types.